# In-Place Upgrade from Windows Server 2008 R2 to 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, team-foundation-server

I realize that this might not be the best place to ask this question but I'm not sure which one of the StackExchange websites this question belongs to except for ServerFault. I currently have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine which has `TFS 2010` and `SQL Server 2008 R2` installed on it. The `IIS` on that machine is also currently hosting several web applications.

I'm trying to perform an in-place upgrade to `Windows Server 2012`, but I'm not sure if it would affect `TFS`, `SQL Server` and `IIS`. I was just wondering if anyone has ever done this and would be able to advise me on it. Is there anything in particular that will need to be reconfigured after the upgrade? Will all settings automatically be migrated as well (for example, do I have to reconfigure all my custom firewall exceptions?) Of course I will get a full backup of the server but it'd be really disappointing to see for example all my TFS collections are gone or that the database is wiped out. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: P2V it into a test VM and, uh, test it.

Comment: 1) you can backup TFS beforehand just in case.  2) why not P2V it to a temp VM somewhere, upgrade the VM, and test.  EDIT: whatever Hampton...horrible idea. :)

Comment: `if anyone has ever done this and would be able to advise me on it.` Advice #1, make and verify full backups.  Advice #2: don't do in-place upgrade if you can possibly avoid it.  Advice #3: if you ignore #2, then clone the original and test in a VM first.

Comment: @TheCleaner What do you have against testing?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - nothing against it...my "EDIT" above was because you beat me by 4 seconds...

Comment: Restore the backups to a vm then test the upgrade on the vm.  Then you know the backups work properly as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like TFS 2010 isn't even supported on Windows Server 2012: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592(v=vs.100).aspx.

Anyway, an in-place OS upgrade on a server hosting SQL Server and TFS is something I'd really prefer to avoid.